# add_custom_target SOURCES option adds dependency to MAIN_DEPENDENCY custom commands

Tags: cmake

Given the following CMakeLists.txt and some arbitrary hello.c:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

get_filename_component(debug_rpath ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/hello-debug.exe REALPATH)
message(STATUS "debug exe: ${debug_rpath}")
get_filename_component(release_rpath ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/hello-release.exe REALPATH)
message(STATUS "release exe: ${release_rpath}")

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT hello-release.exe
  COMMAND clang ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/hello.c -O3 -o ${release_rpath}
  MAIN_DEPENDENCY hello.c
#  DEPENDS hello.c
  IMPLICIT_DEPENDS hello.c
  COMMENT "Compiling release..."
  VERBATIM)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${debug_rpath}
  COMMAND clang ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/hello.c -g -DNDEBUG -o ${debug_rpath}
  MAIN_DEPENDENCY hello.c
#  DEPENDS hello.c
  IMPLICIT_DEPENDS hello.c
  COMMENT "Compiling debug..."
  VERBATIM)


add_custom_target(hello-release ALL
  DEPENDS ${release_rpath}
  SOURCES hello.c
  VERBATIM)


add_custom_target(hello-debug ALL
  DEPENDS ${debug_rpath}
  SOURCES hello.c
  VERBATIM)
```

(debug/release and clang as compiler are examples, I know cmake has its own mechanism for that. The important detail is that I have two custom commands using the the same main input file)

Executing the `hello-debug` target outputs:

```
> mingw32-make hello-debug
[ 50%] Compiling release...
[100%] Compiling debug...
[100%] Built target hello-debug
```

Why does it also build release?

Uncommenting the `SOURCES` or `MAIN_DEPENDENCY` options builds just the chosen target. I understand the documentation like the two options only influence Visual Studio project generation. I use "MinGW Makefiles" and "Visual Studio" generators at the same time, therefore keeping the SOURCES option would actually be nice. Bug or am I overseeing something?

Comment: Found probably related problem: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-May/029591.html